# sending data from angular to node api

Tags: node.js, angular, sequelize.js

i am beginner so i apologize if my question isn't relevant or easy to fix, but i couldn,t fix my issue yet, for 4 days.

I am working on an api, which will receive data from angular form, then store it with sequelize on a mariadb table.

When i submit my form, which would through the url, post it in the table through the api, i can see that the req.body is defined, and it reachs the api, but yet i have and error in my angular http post which is thrown(error 500).
With postman, i see that my url isn t reachable, i can't figure out so if my error comes from the post angular, or the backend with my model, even if error 500 is for back end.

I tried to redefine my sequelize model, parse and stringify the object i send, try others url...but nothing works.

So here is my function called when the form is submitted,the function formatrequestschedulest return the object i want to post.

```
onSubmitScheduled(){
    let OndemandScheduledRequest = this.formatRequestScheduled(this.selectedHotel, this.selectedCheckInDate, this.selectedCheckOutDate, this.selectedNumber, this.selectedCurrency, this.selectedReportName, this.selectedUser, this.selectedEmail, this.selectedFormat);

    console.log(OndemandScheduledRequest);
    this.saveScheduledRequest(OndemandScheduledRequest);
    return this.openDialog();
  }


    saveScheduledRequest(onDemandScheduledRequest: OnDemandScheduledRequest){
       this.http.post('/api/ScheduledReport', JSON.stringify(onDemandScheduledRequest), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
         .subscribe(res=>{ console.log(res
         )
           console.log('ok')},
         (err) =>
           console.log('an error'))
           /*console.log(err))*/
    }
```

And here is my api:

```
var request= require('../controller/ondemandscheduledrequests');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/getreport',request.create);
router.post('/ScheduledReport',request.create);
```

I can provide also the error i get, but i don't know if i can join a picture to the question.

I just want to have my form data store to my table, but i get an error 500 instead.

[this is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTnK9.png)

Comment: See here how to add an image to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe like below and try once

```
  this.http.post('/ScheduledReport', JSON.stringify(onDemandScheduledRequest).pipe().subscribe(val => {
            console.log(val, "service");
          , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})}
```

Comment: it is because i use router as subpath , so i have in my server config file an app.use('/api',api)

Comment: Are you running your server code(backend) while running your client code(ui)